# Redirect in POST in expressjs

Tags: node.js, post, express, response

Can i send a response to different route; rather then the one, which the request comes from ? 
Here is my app.post():

```
exports.searchUser = function(req, res){
 var searchStr = req.param('searchStr', null);
 if ( null == searchStr ) {
  res.send(400);
  return;
 }

 models.User.findByString(searchStr, function onSearchDone(err,users) {
  if (err || users.length == 0) {
   res.send(404);
  } else {
  res.send(users);
  res.redirect('contacts/find');
  }
 });
}
```

res.send(users) send response to the same route where POST requested.. I want to send the respond to the different route. is it possible ?

Comment: You can't do send and redirect both on the same request.

Comment: is there an another way to send JSON to any route ?

Comment: No, unless you save it then retrieve it. When you do redirect, the request is sent to that route along with all its data.